# Angular localize in jasmine unit test

Tags: angular, typescript, localization, jasmine, angular-localize

I am trying to test translation in angular with jasmine. I am using angular localize but I do not know how to use it inside jasmine/karma unit tests. I trigger language change via URL parameter which is suitable for e2e tests where it works fine. Thanks for any suggestions on how to change language in jasmine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved.

tsconfig

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
```

spec file

```
import { loadTranslations } from '@angular/localize';
import de from '../assets/de.json';
loadTranslations(de);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working scenario (hard to find such an example), but with a little modification. The function `loadTranslations` needs a record <string, string>, but those days this message file contains all translations under translations key.

`loadTranslation(de.translations)` should be correct.